# Free 100 rep on every Stack Exchange account including the parent account?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, association

I got a 100 rep association bonus for every one of my Stack Exchange accounts when I passed 200 rep on Stack Overflow. But I was a little surprised when I saw that I got 100 rep for my Stack Overflow account as well. It was the account which caused the bonus to happen on all other sites.

I didn't understand the logic behind this, to give the bonus for the parent account as well. I'm happy to get it, and if it's a bug please don't take it away again. But is it?

Comment: From the dupe *"you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 **on each site**"*. So it's by design and not a bug.